# Rcpp how to give vector of a given length identical values in each cell

Tags: r, rcpp

In the code below, the out of the vectorTest function is limited by the number of items in Tglobe. As written the output is 101. If Tglobe = c(100, 101), the output is 101, 102.

What I want to do is create a vector with the size of speed and fill it with identical values. In other words, with `Tglobe <- 100`, I want the output to be 101, 102, 103, 104, 105

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector vectorTest(Rcpp::NumericVector Tglobe, Rcpp::NumericVector speed) {
  Rcpp::NumericVector test(speed.size(), NAN);
  test = Tglobe + speed;
  return(test);
}

/*** R
speed <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
Tglobe <- 100
vectorTest(Tglobe, speed)
*/
```

Comment: Does it satisfy you if you just change "Rcpp::NumericVector Tglobe" to "double const& Tglobe" in the arg of the function ? That way cpp know you want to add a single double with a vector

Comment: Spot on and basically what I just did in the answer below.  But you also need to stick `Tglobe` into the ctor to assign, and as C++ does not "recycle" (in the R sense) or "broadcast" you need to ensure matching dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little oddly worded. So I read it as a

- *How do instantiate a vector with a given scalar?*  Which you already answered albeit by sticking the wrong value (`NAN`, not even a C++ constant) in
- *How do I add two vectors?* which you already answered too
- *How to I generalize to an input vector (and return matrix)?* which is left as an exercise.

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector vectorTest(double globe, Rcpp::NumericVector speed) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector globevec(speed.size(), globe);
    return globevec + speed;
}

/*** R
speed <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
Tglobe <- 100
vectorTest(Tglobe, speed)
*/
```

#### Output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/68784602/answer.cpp")

> speed <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

> Tglobe <- 100

> vectorTest(Tglobe, speed)
[1] 101 102 103 104 105
>
```

Comment: @JerryN : You seem to be developing a habit of dropping questions here, not engaging and not accepting answers to those question.  May I make a small suggestion?  That is not helping in getting more or better answers.

Comment: Dirk, Not my intention. I try to accept answers and flag (positively) good comments. I'll go back and see what I missed.

Comment: Thank you.  And I was aware you didn't _always_ leave them hanging or I would have fully ignored you ;-)  Appreciate it.

Comment: One (of the many) things I like about your answers is that you try to give some explanation. One thing that has been puzzling me and I haven't found a good answer to is when to use double and when NumericVector. I suspect it has something to do with the specifics of variable type. I don't actually want you to answer this question directly but rather to point me to some place that has some discussion about this. You had posted the following in one answer to a question about this but I'm looking for a bit more general discussion. One suggestion you had was your book. ... more in the next comment

Comment: Here's what you said in an earlier answer "All of the Rcpp(11) types are "thin proxy objects" (which we talk about in several places, talks, slide decks, my book, ...) around the underlying SEXP objects. That means no copies are made when you go from R to C++, and when you go back from C++ to R." I'm also embarrassed to report that I just discovered this - https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers.html

Comment: OK. I have just learned that double comes from c++ and numericVector from Rcpp. I have never really understand what Rccp sugar was about. Now I have a bit of an idea.

Comment: A walk in the park helps. Or a past in C (and/or C++). `double` is what Kernighan and Ritchie gave us, and it is a scalar.  Rcpp (via some magic) lets us send and receive doubles, but that is already a trick.  R _just does not have scalar values_ and everything is a vector (even if of length one).  So we need two different things.  If I may, it helps to read a little, maybe old presentations (also look at  https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/presentations.html) and also other people's code. I have been learnig R maybe 25 years, and I still learn from the code by R Core, and from many people for C++.